# How To exit from a Loop In Apache camel/Jboss

Tags: jboss, apache-camel, context.xml

I need to exit from a loop when the body contains 'SUCCEDDED' in Jboss/Apache camel. I have tried using Stop() but that doesnt work since it stops every connection(eg:DBConnection).

Here is the sample code:
        
            
            
                60
                
                    10000
                
                
                
                    
                        ${body} 
        contains 'SUCCEEDED'

```
                    <CXF bean call />
                    <log loggingLevel="INFO"
                        message="response 
    : ${body}">
                        <description>Logs the 2nd SOAP Response.</description>
                    </log>
                    <setBody>
                        <xpath>{{status.xpath}}</xpath>
                    </setBody>
                    <convertBodyTo type="java.lang.String" />
                </otherwise>
            </choice>
        </loop>
        <to uri="direct:loopend">
        </to>
    </route>
```

Comment: See the loop with doWhile which requires Camel 2.17 onwards: http://camel.apache.org/loop